# How to substitute numbers in a two column array with corresponding strings in another file using Python or bash?

Tags: python, arrays, bash, file

I have two files, 1 contains a two column array of numbers

File 1:

```
1  3

2  3

2  1

34 2

...
```

File 2:

```
1   CA1

2   CB1

3   CC1

34   DD1

...
```

Therefore I would like my output file to look like this

```
CA1 CC1

CB1 CC1

CC1 CA1

DD1 CB1
```

Comment: What have you tried? Not a hard problem in any sense, as long as you know how to read lines and tokenize them, which is one of the most basic things in any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> with open('file2') as f:
...     values = [i.strip() for i in f if i.strip() != '']

>>> d = dict([i.split() for i in values])

>>> with open('file1') as f:
...     keys = [i.strip() for i in f if i.strip() != '']

>>> with open('file3', 'w') as f:
...     for i, j in [i.split() for i in keys]:
...         f.write(d[i]+' '+d[j]+'\n')
```

And check the `file3`.

Comment: I'd say better use descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Here is another approach  
name = dict()
with open('file2', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    col = line.split()
    name[col[0]] = col[1]

with open('file1', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    col = line.split()
    print('{} {}'.format(name[col[0]], name[col[1]]))
```